# NumPy: create ndarray of objects

Tags: python, numpy

I like to create a numpy array -- with a shape, say [2, 3], where each array element is a list. Yes, I know this isn't efficient, or even desirable, and all the good reasons for that -- but can it be done?

So I want a 2x3 array where each point is a length 2 vector, *not* a 2x3x2 array. Yes, really.

If I fudge it by making it ragged, it works:

```
>>> np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [9, 8], [2, 4, -1]], dtype=object).reshape([2, 3])
array([[list([0, 0]), list([0, 1]), list([0, 2])],
       [list([1, 0]), list([9, 8]), list([2, 4, -1])]], dtype=object)
```

but if numpy *can* make it fit cleanly, it does so, and so throws an error:

```
>>> np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [9, 8], [2, 4]], dtype=object).reshape([2, 3])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 12 into shape (2,3)
```

So putting aside your instincts that this is a silly thing to want to do (it is, and I know this), can I make the last example work somehow to create a shape 2x3 array where each element is a Python list of length 2, without numpy forcing it into 2x3x2?

Comment: Are you trying to keep it a `2x3` array of lists, rather than a `2x3x2` array? Did you try `dtype=list`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you should create an object array with expected shape.

Then, use list to fill the array.

```py
l = [[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]], [[1, 0], [9, 8], [2, 4]]]
arr = np.empty((2, 3), dtype=object)
arr[:] = l
```

Comment: ...huh. I remember that slice assignment not working when I tried it earlier (years ago), but [it seems to work now](https://ideone.com/6wbPKz). Either I'm remembering wrong, or they changed it since then.

Comment: This is beautiful

Comment: I'd like to share my opinion that I do find this question very relevant and deserving upvotes. The answers here prove that this is not trivial, while I think it can be useful in multiple cases and needs, e.g., when integrating Python code with a C application

Comment: @user2357112, perhaps you remember trying to assign an array.  That will produce a `broadcasting` error.  Assigning a list works.

Comment: Nice, that almost does the job, apart from it forces me to first 'nest' the list-of-lists to the right shape -- what I'd ideally want to do is to populate the shaped, empty array from a flat list of values (the len-2 lists) -- analogous to `np.arange(9).resahpe([3, 3])`.

Comment: @xpqz: If that's what you want, you can make a flat array, populate it, and *then* reshape it to whatever shape you want.

Comment: Yes! That does it.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an empty array and fill it with objects manually:

```
>>> a = np.empty((3,2), dtype=object)
>>> a
array([[None, None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
>>> a[0,0] = [1,2,3]
>>> a
array([[list([1, 2, 3]), None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

Anwering my own question, based on the fine answers provided by others, here's what I did:

```
l = [
    np.array([0, 0]), 
    np.array([0, 1]), 
    np.array([0, 2]), 
    np.array([1, 0]),
    np.array([9, 8]),
    np.array([2, 4])
]

arr = np.empty(len(l), dtype=object)
arr[:] = l
arr = arr.reshape((2, 3))
```

which gives

```
array([[array([0, 0]), array([0, 1]), array([0, 2])],
       [array([1, 0]), array([9, 8]), array([2, 4])]],  dtype=object)
```

which is exactly what I wanted. Thanks all!

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that the objects you wanted to assign were numpy arrays rather than lists